# Visual Studio 2010 does not warn about build errors when starting to debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I started using Visual Studio 2010 and am missing the dialog box that used pop up in Visual Studio 2008 and earlier that would warn you if there are build errors. The text was something along the line of "There were build errors, would you like to continue using the last successful build?" Then you had the option to continue or cancel (and then go fix the build errors.)

VS2010 is immediately debugging with the last successful build when there are build errors. This is causing frustration for me. How do I turn this warning back on in VS2010? I looked through the options, but didn't see anything that looked like it would work.

Answer (score 4):

This is the setting: **Prompt to launch**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

tools - options - projects and solutions - build and run -"on run, when build or deployment errors occur"